# perl unpack function to python

Tags: python, unpack

I am trying to translate a Perl script into Python.

I have some trouble translating this line:

```perl
my ($sync,$pid,$afccc,@bytes)=unpack('CnCC*',$pkt);
```

I tried this in Python

```py
bytes=[]
sync,pid,afccc,bytes=struct.unpack_from('BHBB',pkt)
```

But the variable bytes is not a list after this line, then the execution fails.

FYI, pkt is a 188 chars long string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems, only one of which was fixed in Python 3:

1. `struct.unpack` doesn't support arbitrary repetition. (Python 3.4 introduced `iter_unpack`, but that doesn't really help here.) You need an exact
    count for each specifier. You can't write `'BHB*B'`; instead, you need to compute the number of bytes expected after `BHB`. Fortunately, it's not that hard or ugly to do:

   ```
   header_fmt = struct.Struct('BHB')
   packet_fmt = struct.Struct(header_fmt.format +
                              '{}B'.format(188 - header_fmt.size))
   # packet_fmt.format == 'BHB183B'
   ```

   (In general you might need to use `len(pkt)` instead of hardcoding 188.)

   `'BHB*B'`, though would be nice.
2. In Python 2, you have to extract the trailing bytes from the array explicitly:

   ```
   fields = packet_fmt.unpack(pkt)
   sync, pid, afccc = fields[3:]
   bytes = fields[3:]
   ```

   Alternatively, you can use `unpack_from` and splicing, since you don't unpack bytes so much as you extract them.

   ```
   sync, pid, afccc = header_fmt.unpack_from(pkt)
   bytes = pkt[header_fmt.size:]
   ```

   In Python 3, you can just use `*name` syntax with tuple unpacking.

   ```
   sync, pid, afccc, *bytes = packet_fmt.unpack(pkt)
   ```